# View header information of FITS file

Tags: import, fits-format

I'm dealing with .fits (.fit) files with Mathematica, and these files are [Fermi LAT GRBs](https://fermi.gsfc.nasa.gov/ssc/observations/types/grbs/lat_grbs/table.php) data. We can import one of them by `Import["https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/fermi/data/gbm/triggers/
2017/bn170306588/current/glg_trigdat_all_bn170306588_v01.fit"]` for example.

Every fit file has its header imformation, and we can read it via [fv](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftools/fv/), and it looks just like that:

[image: header of fits file]

I cannot find any way to read the header of FITS file in Mathematica. So my question is this:

**Is there any way to read FITS header information ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
file = "https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/fermi/data/gbm/triggers/2017/bn170306588/current/glg_trigdat_all_bn170306588_v01.fit";
```

you can try

```
Import[file, "RawMetaInformation"]
```

You can find out about other accessible import elements with

```
Import[file, "Elements"]
```

> {"Airmass", "Author", "BitDepth", "Channels", "ColorSpace", "Comments", "Data", "DataType", "Declination", "Device", "Dimensions", "Equinox", "ExposureTime", "Extensions", "Graphics", "HDUCount", "History", "HourAngle", "Image", "ImageSize", "IndexedAssociation", "MetaInformation", "Object", "ObservationDate", "Observer", "Organization", "Plaintext", "Range", "RawData", "RawMetaInformation", "Reference", "RightAscension", "SiderealTime", "Summary", "SummarySlideView", "TableData", "TableHeaders",
>   "TableUnits", "Telescope"}

Answer (score 1):

```
Import["https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/fermi/data/gbm/triggers/2017/bn170306588/current/glg_trigdat_all_bn170306588_v01.fit", 
  "MetaInformation"]
```

yields a massive nested `Association` containing the headers for this rather complicated file.